# Where should I set the logic to properly update my Widget?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, widget

**Introduction**

I'm trying to make a **widget for school as homework.** It is done for **Android SO and coded in Java**. I'm pretty new to this so I had to read A LOT of documentation, specially from their main Website for Android Devs, I'm not that interested in Android developing so a quick and solid answer is more than welcome.

**Problem**

I'm sending a name and ID from a WidgetConfig class (an Activity) using an Intent to the widget. This data is supposed to be written on the TextView from the widget layout but for some reason it does not.

In this code below you may see my attempt, if you tested the program from the repository that I will provide you are going to see that it is not properly updated.

So my question is:

**How I can manage to update my widget from data sent from an activity?**

```
 public class FerrixWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {


    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ferrix_widget);
        //views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        RemoteViews spm = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ferrix_widget);
        spm.setTextViewText(R.id.alumnoName, "plsupdate");
    }


    //This is called to update the App Widget at intervals defined by the updatePeriodMillis attribute
    // in the AppWidgetProviderInfo.
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }



    }

    //This is called when an instance the App Widget is created for the first time.
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
        System.out.println("[INFO] FIRST INSTANCE CREATED");
    }

    //This is called when the last instance of your App Widget is deleted from the App Widget host.
    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    //This is called for every broadcast and before each of the above callback methods.
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        RemoteViews controles = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ferrix_widget);

        String alumnoName = intent.getStringExtra("Name"); //Gets the intent withthe key "Name"

        System.out.println("[INFO] Key: Name gets result: " + alumnoName);


        controles.setTextViewText(R.id.alumnoName, alumnoName);
        controles.setTextViewText(R.id.claseName, "DAM2");

        System.out.println("[INFO] Context: " + context);
        System.out.println("[INFO] Received: " + intent.getAction().toString());
    }
}
```

**Full code at**

https://gitlab.com/JonaFerre/ferrixwidget

**My goal**

I want that when you set tup the widget on your screen it pops up a config screen (it does that already), then you insert your name and class, this data is sent over to the widget (via Intent) so it gets written and shown alongside the time of the day and some other stuff (That I will add once I get this properly solved)

**Notes:**

- IDE: Android Studio
- Andriod: v15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix this by updating your widget in widget's *onReceive*:

Just send a broadcast from configuration activity:

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("WidgetPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("msg_" + widgetId, nameInput.getText().toString()); //???
            editor.commit();

            //Actualizar el widget tras la config
            System.out.println("[INFO] Getting instance of WidgetConfig");
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(WidgetConfig.this);
            System.out.println("[INFO] Updating the widget");
            FerrixWidget.updateAppWidget(WidgetConfig.this, appWidgetManager, widgetId);


            //Devolver un buen OK
            Intent resultado = new Intent();
            resultado.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
            //System.out.println("[CONFIG INFO] Name text is: " + nameInput.getText().toString());
            resultado.putExtra("Name", nameInput.getText().toString());
            resultado.setAction("myUpdate");
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), FerrixWidget.class);
            resultado.setComponent(componentName);
            sendBroadcast(resultado);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
            finish();
            System.out.println("[INFO] OK devuelto!");
        }
 });
```

and on widget's *onReceive*

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("myUpdate")) {
        RemoteViews controles = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ferrix_widget);

        String alumnoName = intent.getStringExtra("Name"); //Gets the intent withthe key "Name"
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);


        System.out.println("[INFO] Key: Name gets result: " + alumnoName);


        controles.setTextViewText(R.id.alumnoName, alumnoName);
        controles.setTextViewText(R.id.claseName, "DAM2");
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(id, controles);

        System.out.println("[INFO] Context: " + context);
        System.out.println("[INFO] Received: " + intent.getAction().toString());
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

But the better way is to save your data and widget's id in db/preference and just update on widget's side in onUpdate.

Please, just read [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets). There a lot of stuff that can helps you.

Comment: The db implementation it's my final goal, but before that, I needed to understand this properly. Many thanks!